# @JdbcTest detect class annotated @SpringBootApplication

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-test

I've tried the `@JdbcTest` on following project structure.

```
.
├── pom.xml
└── src
    ├── main
    │   ├── java
    │   │   └── com
    │   │       └── example
    │   │           ├── Application.java
    │   │           ├── repository
    │   │           │   └── DemoRepository.java
    │   │           └── service
    │   │               └── DemoService.java
    │   └── resources
    │       └── application.properties
    └── test
        └── java
            └── com
                └── example
                    ├── ApplicationTests.java
                    └── repository
                        └── DemoRepositoryTests.java
```

DemoRepository.java (test target)

```
package com.example.repository;

import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcOperations;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public class DemoRepository {

    private final JdbcOperations jdbcOperations;

    DemoRepository(JdbcOperations jdbcOperations) {
        this.jdbcOperations = jdbcOperations;
    }

    public int findNumber() {
        return jdbcOperations.queryForObject("SELECT 1",int.class);
    }

}
```

DemoRepositoryTests.java (test class)

```
package com.example.repository;

import org.assertj.core.api.Assertions;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.jdbc.JdbcTest;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Import;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@JdbcTest
@Import(DemoRepository.class)
public class DemoRepositoryTests {

    @Autowired
    private DemoRepository repository;

    @Test
    public void findNumber() {
        Assertions.assertThat(repository.findNumber()).isEqualTo(1);
    }

}
```

Application.java (class annotated `@SpringBootApplication`)

```
package com.example;

import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;

import com.example.service.DemoService;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public CommandLineRunner demo(DemoService service) {
        return args -> System.out.println("Number:" + service.findNumber());
    }

}
```

I've perform `DemoRepositoryTests`. Then following error occurred.

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the auto-configuration report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2017-03-10 23:55:44.092 ERROR 9375 --- [           main] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Parameter 0 of method demo in com.example.Application required a bean of type 'com.example.service.DemoService' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.example.service.DemoService' in your configuration.

2017-03-10 23:55:44.100 ERROR 9375 --- [           main] o.s.test.context.TestContextManager      : Caught exception while allowing TestExecutionListener [org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.SpringBootDependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener@1442d7b5] to prepare test instance [com.example.repository.DemoRepositoryTests@3c0a50da]

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:124) ~[spring-test-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:83) ~[spring-test-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.SpringBootDependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(SpringBootDependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:47) ~[spring-boot-test-autoconfigure-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar:1.5.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:230) ~[spring-test-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:228) [spring-test-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:287) [spring-test-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289) [spring-test-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:247) [spring-test-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:94) [spring-test-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61) [spring-test-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70) [spring-test-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:191) [spring-test-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68) [junit-rt.jar:na]
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:51) [junit-rt.jar:na]
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:237) [junit-rt.jar:na]
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70) [junit-rt.jar:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_112]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_112]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_112]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_112]
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147) [idea_rt.jar:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'demo' defined in com.example.Application: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'demo' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.example.service.DemoService' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:749) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:467) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1173) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1067) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:761) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:866) ~[spring-context-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:542) ~[spring-context-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:737) ~[spring-boot-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar:1.5.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:370) ~[spring-boot-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar:1.5.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:314) ~[spring-boot-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar:1.5.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:120) ~[spring-boot-test-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar:1.5.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:98) ~[spring-test-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:116) ~[spring-test-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    ... 28 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.example.service.DemoService' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoMatchingBeanFound(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1486) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1104) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1066) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:835) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:741) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    ... 46 common frames omitted
```

Reproduce project is

- https://github.com/kazuki43zoo/spring-boot-issues/tree/gh-8566/gh-8566

Is specification for this behavior ?

#### Pre-Conditions

- Spring Boot 1.5.2.RELEASE

Answer (score 4):

I've founded a error reason for this.

## Reason

The `SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper`(`TestContextBootstrapper` used by `@JdbcTest`) find a class annotated `@SpringBootConfiguration` (or `@SpringBootApplication`).

`SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper#getOrFindConfigurationClasses`:

```
protected Class<?>[] getOrFindConfigurationClasses(
        MergedContextConfiguration mergedConfig) {
    Class<?>[] classes = mergedConfig.getClasses();
    if (containsNonTestComponent(classes) || mergedConfig.hasLocations()
            || !mergedConfig.getContextInitializerClasses().isEmpty()) {
        return classes;
    }
    Class<?> found = new SpringBootConfigurationFinder()
            .findFromClass(mergedConfig.getTestClass()); // #### This !! ###
    Assert.state(found != null,
            "Unable to find a @SpringBootConfiguration, you need to use "
                    + "@ContextConfiguration or @SpringBootTest(classes=...) "
                    + "with your test");
    logger.info("Found @SpringBootConfiguration " + found.getName() + " for test "
            + mergedConfig.getTestClass());
    return merge(found, classes);
}
```

`SpringBootConfigurationFinder#findFromClass` find from same package with test class at first. If not exist with same package, it recursively find from parent package.

`SpringBootConfigurationFinder#scanPackage`:

```
private Class<?> scanPackage(String source) {
    while (source.length() > 0) {
        Set<BeanDefinition> components = this.scanner.findCandidateComponents(source); // ### Find ###
        if (!components.isEmpty()) {
            Assert.state(components.size() == 1,
                    "Found multiple @SpringBootConfiguration annotated classes "
                            + components);
            return ClassUtils.resolveClassName(
                    components.iterator().next().getBeanClassName(), null);
        }
        source = getParentPackage(source); // ### Fallback ###
    }
    return null;
}
```

## Possible Solutions (Workarounds?)

1. Remove bean definition and dependency injection on class that annotated `@SpringBootApplication` or `@SpringBootConfiguration`.
2. Load custom configuration class(not annotated `@TestConfiguration`) on test class.

   e.g.) Use static inner class

   ```
   @RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
   @JdbcTest
   @Import(DemoRepository.class)
   public class DemoRepositoryTests {
       // ...    
       @Configuration
       static class Config { // ### Add
       }
   }
   ```

   e.g.) Use shared configuration class for testing

   ```
   @JdbcTest
   @Import(DemoRepository.class)
   @ContextConfiguration(classes = TestConfig.class) // ### Add
   public class DemoRepositoryTests {
       // ...    
   }
   ```
3. Create `@SpringBootApplication` class for testing into same package.

   ```
   package com.example.repository;

   import org.springframework.boot.SpringBootConfiguration;

   @SpringBootApplication
   class RepositoryTestApplication {

   }
   ```
4. and more ... ?

I think solution 3 is good choice.

Answer (score 4):

I experienced the same issue when trying to setup the test approach for my Repository using `@JdbcTest`.

Here my solution after reviewing Spring Boot Reference document and source codes referred by Andy Wilkinson.

1. Prevent `@JdbcTest` to search the primary configuration annotated with `@SpringBootApplication`, and other `@Configuration` by declaring the inner class annotated with `@Configuration`. The inner `@Configuration` class will override as the primary configuration which is currently empty as per the following codes.

> ```
> @RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
> @JdbcTest
> @Import({TestConfiguration.class, DemoRepository.class})
> @AutoConfigureTestDatabase
> @TestPropertySource(properties = {"spring.datasource.schema=classpath:dbschema.sql"})
> public class DemoRepositoryTest {
>   //This is the main key to override the search done by @JdbcTest to
>   //those annotated with @SpringBootApplication, other @Configuration
>   @Configuration
>   @EnableAutoConfiguration 
>   static class Config {
>   }
>   @Autowired
>   DemoRepository repository;
>   @Before
>   public void setUp() throws Exception {
>   ...
>   }
>   @Test
>   public void findOne() throws Exception {
>   ...
>   }
> }
> ```

2. I am using `NamedParameterJdbcDaoSupport`, so here is how I configure the `DataSource`

> ```
> @TestConfiguration
> public class TestConfiguration {
>     //SpringBoot Test AutoConfig will inject the memory db here.
>     @Autowired
>     DataSource dataSource;
>
>     @Bean
>     public NamedParameterJdbcDaoSupport jdbcDaoSupport() {
>
>         NamedParameterJdbcDaoSupport support = new NamedParameterJdbcDaoSupport();
>         support.setDataSource(dataSource);
>
>         return support;
>     }
> }
> ```

3. `DemoRepository.java`

> ```
> @Repository
> public class DemoRepository {
>
>     private final NamedParameterJdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;
>
>     public DemoRepository(NamedParameterJdbcDaoSupport jdbcDaoSupport) {
>
>         this.jdbcTemplate = jdbcDaoSupport.getNamedParameterJdbcTemplate();
>
>     }
> ```

4. Declare Memory DB Driver in `pom.xml`, h2 as example here:

   ```
   <dependency>
       <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
       <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
       <scope>test</scope>
       <version>1.4.196</version>
   </dependency>
   ```

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/17677793)

Comment: It does in point 1. I have updated the description for the same.

Answer (score -1):

You do not have an application context with just **@JdbcTest & @Import**, you need to do the same thing as your **ApplicationTests** is declare **@SpringBootTest**

Comment: Thanks for your comment ! Why is it need ? I want to know reason !!

Comment: Sorry, but this answer is wrong. There's no need to use `@SpringBootTest` as well. [Here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/2577d79ff1ceea2b83ace31690c699263eb042f1/spring-boot-test-autoconfigure/src/test/java/org/springframework/boot/test/autoconfigure/jdbc/JdbcTestIntegrationTests.java) is one of Spring Boot's own Integration tests that only uses `@JdbcTest`

Comment: @AndyWilkinson Thanks for your comment! I've added new possible solution (solution 3) on my self answer.

Comment: Sorry @AndyWilkinson, I know there is no need to use @SpringBootTest to test JDBC integration, but in this context we need solve this error exception : `Error creating bean with name 'demo' defined in com.example.Application` , and my suggestion is one way to solve it. Please correct me if anything wrong in this context, and thanks for your feedback on my answer. I checked out author's source code demo here - https://github.com/kazuki43zoo/spring-boot-issues/tree/gh-8566/gh-8566